# FactoryGirl step_definitions inclusion causes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot

I'm using FactoryGirl successfully, but I've just tried requiring the factory_girl/step_definitions file and am getting the backtrace shown below.

The error disappears if I remove the require of factory_girl/step_definitions.

The require is done in my features/support/env.rb in the spark prefork block (though I'm not currently running these tests with spork active).

Using Ruby 1.9.2.

Anyone ever seen this error?  Any thoughts?

Relevant portion of my gemset

```
capybara (1.1.2)
ci_reporter (1.7.0)
factory_girl_rails (3.2.0, 3.0.0)
rails (3.1.0)
rspec (2.9.0)
rspec-core (2.9.0)
rspec-expectations (2.9.1)
rspec-mocks (2.9.0)
rspec-rails (2.9.0)
cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
```

features/support/env.rb details:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do

  require 'cucumber/rails'
  require 'factory_girl'
  require 'factory_girl/step_definitions'

  Capybara.default_selector = :xpath


  ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

  begin
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  rescue NameError
    raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
  end


  Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation


end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

Backtrace detail:

```
Testing started at 11:07 AM ...
Using the default and skip_broken profiles...
uninitialized constant TestItemSetting (NameError)
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:43:in `constantize'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/factory_girl-3.2.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:25:in `build_class'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/factory_girl-3.2.0/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb:100:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/factory_girl-3.2.0/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb:99:in `each'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/factory_girl-3.2.0/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb:99:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/factory_girl-3.2.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:17:in `each'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/factory_girl-3.2.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:17:in `each'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/factory_girl-3.2.0/lib/factory_girl/disallows_duplicates_registry.rb:7:in `each'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/factory_girl-3.2.0/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb:97:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/wwilliam/Development/projectset/projectset/features/support/env.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
/Users/wwilliam/Development/projectset/projectset/features/support/env.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/wwilliam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@projectset/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/wwilliam/Development/projectset/projectset/script/cucumber:9:in `load'
/Users/wwilliam/Development/projectset/projectset/script/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Maybe some code in or around `uninitialized constant TestItemSetting (NameError)`

Comment: @DVG I don't have that code anywhere in my project, nor does a search find it.  I believe it's part of FactoryGirl.

Comment: Gotcha. COuld you post what's going on in this section: `/Users/wwilliam/Development/projectset/projectset/features/support/env.rb:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/wwilliam/Development/projectset/projectset/features/support/env.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'` That seems to be the only code of yours that's getting executed

Comment: @DVG post edited to include env.rb contents

Comment: ARe you in some way modifying factories at runtime? If not, why are you calling `FactoryGirl.reload`?

Comment: @DVG I'm an idiot.  I totally forgot about the rails convention of camel casing underscored variables.  So yes, there was a runtime definition of `factory :test_item_setting`.  And that factory wasn't working because another developer removed the TestItemSetting class.  If you want to create some sort of answer that encapsulates this troubleshooting, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining because of a problem with the runtime definition of factory test_item setting, as discussed in the comments. Glad you got it figured out :)